# Getting associated img from HTML area

Tags: javascript, image, dom-events, area

There are two **img** elements that use the same **map** with one area. Now, we bind e.g. a click event handler to the **area** element. Is it possible to determine from the event handler which image instance has been clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can determine which image was clicked on by either:

1. attaching a single event handler
   on a parent element and inspecting
   the event.target property
2. attaching individual event handlers
   on each image element.

For example, if your HTML looks like:

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="myimage1" usemap="theMap" />
    <img id="myimage2" usemap="theMap" />
    <map name="theMap">
    ...
    </map>
</div>
```

then the possible solutions are:

1)

```
document.getElementById('container').onclick = function(evt) {
    var target = evt.target || window.event.srcElement;

    switch(target.id) {

        case 'myimage1':
            alert('you clicked on myimage1');
            break;

        case 'myimage2':
            alert('you clicked on myimage2');
            break;

        default:
            // click handler got some other evet
    }
}
```

2)

```
document.getElementById('myimage1').onclick = function() {
    alert('you clicked on myimage1');
}
document.getElementById('myimage2').onclick = function() {
    alert('you clicked on myimage2');
}
```

Depending on what you want to do after you capture the event, you'll have to return either 'true' to allow the URL to follow through, or 'false' to take an alternate action.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use its **offsetParent** property. This way, I get the parent, which is what I originally needed. Finding the image itself also shouldn't be too difficult, provided that the images are contained in different **div**s.